# Trying to obtain the title of a website that is generated through javascript

Tags: python, selenium

When I load up a website, its title is "Loading..." for a second, until it changes to a different title obtained through javascript. In python, I'm trying to obtain the generated title.

I've tried using selenium and PhantomJS, but I run into a number of problems.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='/usr/local/lib/phantoms/bin/phantomjs')
driver.get(www.google.com)
p_element = driver.find_element_by_id(id='intro-text')
print(p_element.text)
```

That says that the support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, so I'm not sure what else to do, or if there's an easier method to obtain the result I need.

Comment: phantomJS is deprecated, use Chrome or Firefox, both have headless modes in recent versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like Firefox or Chrome and then use the title property of the driver

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
print(driver.title)
```

If the title briefly shows "Loading..." then you can loop getting the title until it no longer shows "Loading...."

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
while driver.title == 'Loading...':  //Should loop here until title changes
     pass
print(driver.title)
```

My python is rusty, but this should be close.

Comment: Thank you for replying. What I get with this is "while driver.title == 'Loading...' invalid syntax"

Comment: Rusty python....Add the colon at the end and the line below indent and add pass.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: This works perfectly, having added the headless browser option, and adding the geckodriver executable. I have a couple questions, though. What's the best way to add more urls instead of one? And the time it takes to return the title is a little slow. It's not a big deal, but would there be a feasible way to speed it up?

Comment: You could use a variable for the url you want to navigate to and then just pass that to driver.get(someVariable).  You could put this into some loop where you read from a data file, so a foreach loop through the contents and read in the url and title expected and do the same above with that.  Hard to give specifics without knowing exactly what you want to do.

Comment: If you found my answer to be helpful please select it as the answer. This helps us all build our reputation score.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wait, some examples here https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/wait-commands/